# Volatile int vs int variable effect

Tags: c, variables, volatile

If we write:

```
int x=GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R & 0x01; //GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R is a 
                                //volatile type variable storing data register value
 while(1) {
 if(x==1) {do this}
 if(x==2) {do that}
 }
```

Would the value of x become fixed (equal to the value read from the data register in the starting) or will it also change as data register changes? 
Will there be any change if we declare x as volatile!

Comment: Initializations are done *once* and *copies* the value into the variable.

Comment: The only effect of volatile is to warn the compiler that the value of `x` might be changed *from another thread*. This thread only sets the value of `x` once in the initializer and never changes it. Declaring it volatile won't change that. But it probably will force the compiler to read the value of `x` twice inside the loop rather than just loading it into a register once, in case some other thread changed it between the comparisons.

Comment: The `volatile` qualifier attached to `GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R` means that it must be read when `x` is initialized.  It is never read again, though — the value in `x` is not itself marked `volatile` (and even if it were, the GPIO register wouldn't be reread with the code shown).  Also, `x` will never equal `2`; it will contain `0` or `1`.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker *“The volatile types do not provide inter-thread synchronization, memory ordering, or atomicity.”*  I guess you're confusing with [`_Atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic).

Comment: No, I'm not confused--I never said they provided anything like that. But it *does* force the compiler to make two loads rather than optimizing away the second (although as JL points out it might optimize away the second because x==2 can never be true).